# Workflow action failed to trigger flow?

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow

I'm getting this error everytime I try and save a contact of a specific record type. I appreciate this could be very general and I have not received an email stating further info. What's some common things I should check or disable that could be causing this?

[image: "Workflow ACtion Failed to Trigger Flow"]

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000017y9iQAA) for Salesforce across all instances and scheduled for a Summer 17 release. Does your organization have a namespace enabled? 
Activation/Deactivation of the flow (not the process) would resolve the issue but not sure how you depend on this flow.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a process or flow causes an error. You can get to the specific flow by going to https://INSTANCE.my.salesforce.com/designer/designer.apexp#Id=VERSIONID

Replace INSTANCE with your instance of Salesforce and VERSIONID with the flow version id from the error message.

That will get you to the flow. If it's actually a process, you can get the name of the process from there and then just find it in the process builder.

Once you've identified the flow/process you can diagnose the issue from there.

You can also have the process send email alerts to you by deactivating and then reactivating the flow. Unfortunately flow error emails just go to the last person to activate the flow so if it wasn't you then it's a little harder to figure out what's going on.